# Which version of Eclipse support Java 8?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I'm looking for a bundle to download and it is unclear if any of them have Java 8 support. I'm interested in Eclipse for Java EE developers bundle.

Comment: Have a go at IDEA, it has had support for Java 8 for quite a few months

Comment: Yep, but IDEA is not free

Comment: @Artem Have you heard of the Community Edition?

Comment: I used to work with eclipse and know it relatively well including settings and keys. I also use it to develop in Java EE which means that IDEA CE might not work for me. I'm sure that IDEA is a great product and better than Eclipse feature wise, but in my case I'd prefer to stick to Eclipse so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instructions on how to use Java 8 for eclipse can be found [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_%28BETA%29). Note, however, that this isn't a public release, and there are likely still bugs with it. Both Netbeans and IntelliJ IDEA have better support for Java 8, at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You might very well be in luck, support for Java 8 should have gone public yesterday 18th March 2014.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Java8

-Kaz